# Color Coding For A Specific Group Of People

Tags: conditional-formatting

I am tracking time spent with clients using google sheets.  Clients fall into 1 of 3 groups.  I want to have the cell change to a specific color based on the group the client's name is in.  For example, clients 1 & 2 are in group A, clients 3 & 4 are in group B, and clients 5 & 6 in group C.

When I type client 1's name in a cell that is within the identified cell range I want that cell to change to a specific color.  When I type client 4's name in a cell in that same cell range, I want that cell to change to a different color.

My first question is, would this be done using a text file or another sheet linked to the spreadsheet?  Is there a different way to do this?

I know I can use conditional formatting but I would have to create a separate condition for each name, which would be way too time consuming.

Thanks,
K2

I tried using conditional formatting but it would only allow one value using the "Text Contains" option.  This works fine but I would need to do a separate one for each client.

Answer (score 0):

If you have three groups of clients, you can have a range of two columns with the equivalency of the client and the group. For example, in columns H and I:

[image]

Having these columns, you just need three conditional formatting rules that compare the value of the cell and looks it up on the first column, comparing with the second one:

```
=IF(A1="",FALSE,"A"=VLOOKUP(A1,$H:$I,2,0)) //for the green one
=IF(A1="",FALSE,"B"=VLOOKUP(A1,$H:$I,2,0)) //for the yellow one
=IF(A1="",FALSE,"C"=VLOOKUP(A1,$H:$I,2,0)) //for the red one
```

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work.  I created the drop down list of client names in column A from the list of clients I put in column H.  I put the categories in column I.  I then did the conditional formatting -> custom formula is.  I then copied and pasted the formula yow included and selected the corresponding color for the group.  I got an invalid formula error message.

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet to see it in action?

Comment: Never mind, I found the mistake.  I thought the remarks after the // wouldn't be read like other programming languages.  I just removed them and it works like a charm.  Thanks Martin.